# Linkedin API, Access to profile-statistics denied

Tags: api, statistics, linkedin-api, profile

I've created an app and went through the steps described at https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth . With my own profile, I went to the URL:

`https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=<snpi>&redirect_uri=<snip>&state=<snip>&scope=r_emailaddress%20rw_company_admin%20r_basicprofile%20rw_company_admin%20w_share`

and clicked 'Accept'. My app got a code back which I'm using to access my own profile with my app.

This works (I'm passing Authorization Bearer in the headers variable):
`pprint(json.loads(requests.get('https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?format=json', headers=headers).text))`

I'm getting my firstName, headline, id, lastName, siteStandardProfileRequest .

This does not work:
`pprint(json.loads(requests.get('https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/profile-statistics/profile-views?format=json', headers=headers).text))`

I'm getting:

`{'errorCode': 0,
 'message': 'Access to profile-statistics denied',
 'requestId': '<snip>',
 'status': 403,
 'timestamp': 1533557873532}`

Why ? I've set all available permissions in the scope. What am I missing?

PS: My app's statistics show the requests: [stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiNRl.png)